# How can I save values in a array when I have a foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I need to put all the ids in a array when the foreach do his work, cuz right now Im over righting the variable $eduevalid...

```
$edlevel_list = array();

   foreach ($evaluation_list as $evaluation) 
      {
         array_push($edlevel_list, $evaluation);
    $eduevalid = $this->Evaledu_model->getRecordByEvalId($evaluation->id);
      }
```

I need when the foreach pass for the first time save in the array $edlevel_list

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve. Which value are you trying to push to the array? `$evaluation` or `$eduevalid`?

Comment: I just want to grab the ids of the $evaluation and save in array, cuz is ove righting the variable $eduevalid.

Comment: You just need use another array..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use this:

```
$eduevalid[] = $this->Evaledu_model->getRecordByEvalId($evaluation->id);
```

This way every id of the results will be stored into a new index of the array.

Combine with your code:

```
$eduevalid = array();

 foreach ($evaluation_list as $evaluation) 
 {
    $eduevalid[] = $this->Evaledu_model->getRecordByEvalId($evaluation->id);
 }
```

Comment: (assuming this is that the OP needs)

Comment: Now how can i do the logic to this checkbox stay checked when the variable $eduevalid is true? 

echo form_checkbox('edu_level[]','1', in_array('1', $eduevalid));

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. If you want to make the checkbox checked while generating the content, you can use PHP and the HTML attribuut `checked`. However, when you want to do this after the page is loaded you should do this client sided, with javascript. You can always ask a new question, though i suggest to try some things out first and then ask. Goodluck :)

Comment: Yes I want to do after the pages is loaded... and the checkboxes are in a foreach.

Comment: Is your html created with php? if so, does every `$evaluation` stand for a checkbox? I know nothing behind the 5 lines of code i see. There are so many ways this way.

Comment: Yes the html is created with php... yeah the $evaluation stand for checkboxes, is when i check the checkboxs i go for other page with the same checkboxes to evaluated the page, btw the checkbox inthe other page stay checked when i check the first one but then when i go back the checkboxes its suposed to stay checked. How can I do that?

Comment: Define evaluate page, what does it need to do? If you mean it's validating, i suggest your to use javascript instead of redirecting it to another page.

Comment: I suposed to iterate right?

Comment: I don't know what you want to do? Sorry but i suggest you to make a other question of what you try to do. Just explain what you have already tryed and let us see the code with it. People are glad to help you if you show some effort :) I would opened a chat, but you need 25+ reputation for that so.

Comment: Yeah its ok you help alot.... One more question how can I put this array $edulevelid array(); in the variable of $evaluation ?

Comment: $evaluation = $edulevelid will put the array in the other variable. Let me give you one more tip: Use `var_dump(variable);` to see what print your variable :) goodluck

Answer (score 0):

You can form associative result array with elements id=>evalutation:

> ```
> $edlevel_list = array();
>
>    foreach ($evaluation_list as $evaluation) 
>       {
>          $eduevalid = $this->Evaledu_model->getRecordByEvalId($evaluation->id);
>          array_push($edlevel_list, array($eduevalid => $evaluation);
>
>       }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you want to do, just choose one of the solution :

```
foreach ($evaluation_list as $evaluation) 
{
    //get the id
    $eduevalid = $this->Evaledu_model->getRecordByEvalId($evaluation->id);
    //solution one : just store the id in the array
    array_push($edlevel_list, $eduevalid );
    //solution two : use the id as key of your array and store the evaluation object
    $edlevel_list[$eduevalid] = $evaluation;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the job:

```
$edlevel_list = array();
$eduevalid_list = array();

   foreach ($evaluation_list as $evaluation) 
   {
       $edlevel_list[] = $evaluation;
       $eduevalid_list[] = $this->Evaledu_model->getRecordByEvalId($evaluation->id);
   }
```

You will have all the previously re-written `$eduevalid` variable in the `$eduevalid_list` array.

Answer (score 0):

I can't get what are you trying to mean.

But may be could be:

```
   $edlevel_list = array();
   $eduevalid = array();
   foreach ($evaluation_list as $evaluation) 
      {
         $edlevel_list[] =  $evaluation;
         $record = $this->Evaledu_model->getRecordByEvalId($evaluation->id);
         $eduevalid[] = $evaluation->id;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way to store the values in an array using the `foreach loop`. Hope this is what you looking for.

```
$arrayRecords = array();

foreach($evaluation_list as $evaluation){

      $arrayRecords[] = $evaluation;        

}
```

If you have an associative array, then you can do the following.

```
$arrayRecords = array();

foreach($evaluation_list as $key=>$evaluation){

      $arrayRecords[$key] = $evaluation;        

}
```